# How to select first TD inside table which is inside a particular div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want select the first **td** of my table using css selector.
Here is my Html code.

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <table class="mytable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code
**first attempt.**

```
 div.mydiv > table > tbody > tr > td 
    {
        width:25px ;
    }
```

**second attempt**

```
div.mydiv > table  > tr > td 
{
    width:25px ;
}
```

It seems none of them are working.

Regards.

Comment: Please leave your comment before u down vote the question, It may help me to improve question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have one element `.mydiv` table just use `:first-of-type`, `nth-child(1)` or `:first-child`:

```css
div.mydiv td:first-of-type {
    width:25px
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
    <table class="mytable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
                <td>d</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

There is no need of using `!important` here that is bad practice.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div.mydiv > table > tbody > td:first-of-type {
    width:25px !important
}
```

Comment: `... tr > td:first-child` has better compatibility.  This of course assumes OP doesn't need a `th` in the row.

Comment: exact, in which case he'll just change the selector to get past the thead in his row

Answer (score 1):

```
div.mydiv > table > tbody > tr > td:first-child{

}
```

This will select the first child of `tr` which is `td`. This should give you what you need.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:first-child` pseudo-selectors:

```
tr td:first-child
{
    /* styles */
}
```

You could also use ´:first-of-type´.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
table.myTable > tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child {
    width:25px !important;
}
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div.mydiv table.mytable tr > td:first-child {
    width:25px !important;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

See example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/8866/